# How to dynamically remove duplicate JSON Object from JSON String array

Tags: java

I have got the JSON as below

```
{
    "brands": [
        {
            "name": "ACC",
            "quantity": "0",
            "listedbrandID": 1,
            "status": "0"
        }
    ],
    "others": [
        {
            "name": "dd",
            "quantity": "55",
     "listedbrandID": 1

        },
        {
            "name": "dd",
            "quantity": "55",
     "listedbrandID": 1

        }

    ]
}
```

I am trying to remove the dupcate JSON objects from the Others array

I was trying it this way

```
    String JSON = "{
    "brands": [
        {
            "name": "ACC",
            "quantity": "0",
            "listedbrandID": 1,
            "status": "0"
        }
    ],
    "others": [
        {
            "name": "dd",
            "quantity": "55",
     "listedbrandID": 1

        },
        {
            "name": "dd",
            "quantity": "55",
     "listedbrandID": 1

        }

    ]
}" ;


        JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray array = json_obj.getJSONArray("others");
        HashSet<Others> map = new HashSet<Others>();
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length(); k++) {
            Others otherbrands = new Others();
            String name = array.getJSONObject(k).getString("name");
            String quantity = array.getJSONObject(k).getString("quantity");
            String listedbrandID = array.getJSONObject(k).getString("listedbrandID");
            if(name!=null && !name.trim().equals(""))
            {
            otherbrands.setName(name);
            otherbrands.setQuantity(quantity);
            otherbrands.setListedbrandID(listedbrandID);
            map.add(otherbrands);
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length(); k++) 
        {
            String name = array.getJSONObject(k).getString("name");
            System.out.println(name);
            if(!map.contains(name.trim()))
            {
                array.remove(k);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(json_obj);
    }
}


import java.util.Arrays;


public class Others {

    private String name ;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public String getListedbrandID() {
        return listedbrandID;
    }
    public void setListedbrandID(String listedbrandID) {
        this.listedbrandID = listedbrandID;
    }
    private String quantity ;
    private String listedbrandID ;

     @Override
        public boolean equals (Object other)
        {
            if (!(other instanceof Others))
                return false;
            Others ob = (Others) other;
            return name.equals(ob.name) &&
            quantity.equals(ob.quantity);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode ()
        {
            return Arrays.hashCode(new String[]{quantity,name});
        }



}
```

But its printing the entire JSON

Comment: Learn how to keep your indentation consistent -- it makes this question hard to read.

Comment: @AlexisC. so how to resolve this ??

Comment: Why do you have `if(!map.contains(name.trim()))` in first place? Your "map" is an `HashSet<Others>`, so calling contains with a String is a non-sense. (BTW it's a very bad name for a set)

Comment: I am trying to remove all other JSON objects which are not presetn in map

Comment: Why didn't you try to compile your code before sending here? It will obviously fail at the first line.

Comment: @PreethiJain Are you asking for a full-solution? You should think of what you've done first. Why do you think this line of code makes sense for you `if(!map.contains(name.trim()))` ?

Comment: Thanks Alexis , you made a valid point , i have chnaged my code

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

1. `System.out.println(json_obj);` is printing your initial JSON object, you do not seem to be iterating over the set and printing its content. Try:

   `for(Other other : map) System.out.println("Name : " + other.getName() + " ...");`
2. I think you need to add `listedbrandID` in your `equals` method.

To get JSON with only the unique items, you could simply emit the resultant `HashMap`. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730768/how-to-convert-a-list-of-objects-to-a-json-object) previous SO question for more information.

Comment: @npitnti , how can i remove the duplicate JSON objects in this case ??